# Number Theory - Quadratic

Tags: number-theory

How do I find all $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 534$ mod $625$.

I know that since $625$ is $5^4$ this reduces to the solution of the congruence $x^2 \equiv 4$ mod $5$ to which the answers are $\pm 2$. From there how do I ladder up to find the solutions for $x^2 \equiv 9$ mod $25$, and $x^2 \equiv 34$ mod $125$ and finally $x^2 \equiv 534$ mod $625$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modulo $25$, we look for solutions of the form $\pm 2+5t$. Let's deal with $2$. (This will be enough, for if $a$ is a solution of our congruence modulo $625$, then the other solution  is congruent to $-a$ modulo $625$.)

We want $4+20t+25t^2\equiv 9\pmod{25}$, or equivalently $20t\equiv 5\pmod{25}$, or equivalently $4t\equiv 1\pmod{5}$. Thus we can take $t=-1$ or if we prefer positives, $t=4$. That gives the solution $x\equiv 22\pmod{25}$.

Now climb to $125$ in the same way. We want to find $t$ such that $(22+25t)^2\equiv 34\pmod{125}$, or equivalently $484+(2t)(22)(25)\equiv 34\pmod{125}$, or equivalently $(2t)(22)(25)\equiv -450\pmod{125}$, or equivalently $(2t)(22)\equiv -18\pmod{5}$. Now we can solve for $t$, and continue.

For more information, please look under *Hensel Lifting*.

Comment: Thank you. I figured this out by going from $\pm2$ to $pm2 + 5$ which gives either $7,3$ out of which only $\pm3$ is the solution to $x^2 \equiv 9 (\mod 25)$ and then $\pm3 + 25$ gives $22,28$ as possible solutions to the next congruence which on inspection gives $\pm 28$ as the only possible solution and so on.

But I could only do that really since I was at a computer, and this is the theoretical and correct way to do it. I will read up on Hensel Lifting. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. I wanted to use explicitly  the machinery of Hensel Lifting, since it is important, and and works almost as  nicely for any polynomial congruence.